# Is there a log to determine whether an application was launched?

Tags: macos, ms-office, libreoffice

"Someone" downloaded a Word document from a Russian site.  I used [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) to verify that it contained a Word macro virus.  If they just downloaded it and didn't open it then I don't need to reinstall the machine.

This is the link to the [VirusTotal analysis](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/6fcfe1fc636bd68097c1befecb898cda8b273487f0b433569991de6a1e41b990/analysis/1496501483/).

Is there a way to verify that the document was or wasn't opened (e.g. was Word or LibreOffice launched on a particular day)?  Would it be in a log somewhere?

This is for Sierra.

Comment: I might be in the recents list on either app - though tbh, the chances of some random 'foolware' file being targeted at Mac is pretty small.

Comment: Knowing exactly what VirusTotal flagged it as might be useful too.

Comment: It was a Word macro virus.  I would assume these could be cross-platform.  I am not at home so I can't give you the complete signature.

Comment: Not sure on those; would be fun to pull it apart to see. Chances are first thing it tries to do starts with C:\ which will make it pretty useless on a Mac;-)

Comment: If you're seriously interested I can send it to you.  I want to update this question with a more accurate name of the virus anyways.

Comment: just idle curiosity really - I'm not sure it would be wise to post, even temporarily, a link to a known infected file.

Comment: I could post a hex dump.  That should be safe.

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Sierra. I had the tag but I didn't put it in the body of the question.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I've added a link to the VirusTotal analysis.  It says the code is obfuscated so I don't know if you can tell anything from it.  I can post a hexdump of the file if you're interested.